# Getting Multiple Header while merging two CSV file through VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript

```
Sub Tarun()
    Dim sFolderIn   'As String
    Dim sFolderOut  'As String
    Dim sFName      'As String
    Dim sNewFName   'As String
    Dim sData       'As String

    sFolderIn = "C:\Users\tbhalla2\Desktop\tarun"
    sFolderOut = "C:\Users\tbhalla2\Desktop\tarun\New"
    sNewFName = "AllCombined.csv"

    If Dir(sFolderOut, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir sFolderOut
    sFName = Dir(sFolderIn & "\*.csv")
    If sFName <> "" Then
        Open sFolderOut & "\" & sNewFName For Output As #1
        Do
            Open sFolderIn & "\" & sFName For Input As #2
            sData = Input(LOF(2), 2)
            If Len(sData) Then
                Print #1, sData;
                If Right$(sData, 2) <> vbCrLf Then Print #1,
            End If
            Close #2
            Name sFolderIn & "\" & sFName As sFolderOut & "\" & sFName
            sFName = Dir()
        Loop Until sFName = ""
        Close #1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting Header multiple time while merging the file

Header
D
E
F
Header
A
B
C

Answer (score 0):

Before your `Do` loop, create a counter variable, `iFilesRead` for example, and set it to 0.

```
Dim iFilesRead
iFilesRead = 0
```

Then, in your `Do` loop, increment that counter:

```
iFilesRead = iFilesRead + 1
```

This is to track if at least one file has been read and delete the first line after one file has been read.

Before writing `sData` to the output file, check iFilesRead and remove the first line (the header) if necessary (iFilesRead > 1):

```
If iFilesRead > 1 Then
    sData = Mid(sData, InStr(sData, vbCrLf) + 2)
End If
```

Your code should look like this:

```
Do

    Open sFolderIn & "\" & sFName For Input As #2
    sData = Input(LOF(2), 2)

    iFilesRead = iFilesRead + 1

    If Len(sData) Then

        If iFilesRead > 1 Then
            sData = Mid(sData, InStr(sData, vbCrLf) + 2)
        End If

        Print #1, sData;
        If Right$(sData, 2) <> vbCrLf Then Print #1,

    End If

    Close #2

    Name sFolderIn & "\" & sFName As sFolderOut & "\" & sFName
    sFName = Dir()

Loop Until sFName = ""
```